# Error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" al llenar modal para editar registro

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy tratando de llenar un modal Bootstrap al darle click al botón editar del registro correspondiente, pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

¿Qué podré estar haciendo mal? Les adjunto el código que tengo hasta ahora:

Función JavaScript para llenar los input que se encuentran en el modal:

```
function getData(data) {
    d = data.split('||');
    $('#idUserU').val(d[0]);
    $('#nameU').val(d[1]);
    $('#lastnameU').val(d[2]);
    $('#emailU').val(d[3]);
    $('#phoneU').val(d[4]);
}
```

Código PHP para llenar tabla. La variable `$data` me almacena todos los resultados de la consulta, y es la que le paso de parámetro a la función `getData('.$data.');` que mando llamar en el botón editar:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchUser)) {
    $data = $row[0].'||'.$row[1].'||'.$row[2].'||'.$row[3].'||'.$row[4];
    $table .=
    '<tbody><tr>
        <th style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[0].'</th>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[1].'</td>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[2].'</td>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[3].'</td>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[4].'</td>
        <td>
           <div class="form-inline justify-content-center">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-sm-1 mx-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalUpdateUser" onclick="getData('.$data.')"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteUser('.$row[0].')"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
           </div>
        </td>
    </tr></tbody>';
}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano!

Comment: No puedes *pasar* por parámetro una variable de `PHP` a una función de Javascript. Estás mezclando cliente con servidor, un error bastante común cuando se inicia con el stack de PHP y Javascript. Tienes que *pedir* el valor desde Javascript hacia PHP usando una llamada Ajax. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás enviando como parámetro una cadena, pero sin encerrar entre comillas:

```
'... onclick="getData('.$data.') ...'
```

Suponiendo que los datos en `$row` son:

```
0 => 10
1 => Edgar
2 => Saavedra
3 => es@correo.com
4 => 1234567
```

Esa línea en el navegador aparece así:

```
// Todo lo que sigue al 10 es lo que genera error
onclick="getData(10||Edgar||Saavedra||es@correo.com||1234567)"
```

Podrías solucionarlo agregando comillas sencillas para encerrar la cadena, pero debes "escaparlas" anteponiendo una diagonal invertida `\`:

```
'... onclick="getData(\'' . $data . '\') ...'
```

Aunque no es lo ideal. Sería mejor si evitas incluir eventos directamente en las etiquetas y los asignas desde Javascript, obteniendo un HTML más limpio y mejor control sobre los eventos:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchUser)) {
    $table .=
    '<tbody><tr>
        <th style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[0].'</th>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[1].'</td>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[2].'</td>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[3].'</td>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;">'.$row[4].'</td>
        <td>
           <div class="form-inline justify-content-center">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-sm-1 mx-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalUpdateUser"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
           </div>
        </td>
    </tr></tbody>';
}
```

En PHP, no necesitas la variable `$data` porque ya tienes toda la información necesaria en cada celda. Tampoco asignas evento a los botones, eso lo haces directamente en Javascript.

Ya que estás usando *jQuery* puedes delegar el evento clic al cuerpo de la tabla:

```
// Escuchar clics en cuerpo de tabla
// Y "filtrar" para obtener solo botones para modificar, por su clase
$('#id-de-tabla tbody').on('click', 'btn-primary', function() {
    // $(this) representa el botón que recibió clic
    // Con .closest() puedes acceder al padre (fila de la tabla)
    let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    // Con .find() obtienes todas las celdas de la fila
    let celdas = $(tr).find('td');
    // Usas .eq() para acceder a cada celda por su posición (0 en adelante)
    // .text() devuelve el contenido del elemento
    $('#idUserU').val($(celdas).eq(0).text());
    $('#nameU').val($(celdas).eq(1).text());
    $('#lastnameU').val($(celdas).eq(2).text());
    $('#emailU').val($(celdas).eq(3).text());
    $('#phoneU').val($(celdas).eq(4).text());
});

// Función para eliminar
$('#id-de-tabla tbody').on('click', 'btn-danger', function() {
    // Simplificando con una sola línea para obtener ID
    let id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();
});
```

Comment: Sí me funcionó! Muchas gracias por tu apoyo y recomendaciones amigo :)